# Why do the ngModelCtrl.$formatters get run from last to first

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

The ngModelCtrl.$parsers gets run through from the first parser in the array to the last parser in the array, while ngModelCtrl.$formatters gets run through from the last formatter in the array to the first formatter in the array. Just wondering the rationale behind this.

Snippet from angular.js (v1.2.1):

```
  ...
  var formatters = ctrl.$formatters,
      idx = formatters.length;

  ctrl.$modelValue = value;
  while(idx--) {
    value = formatters[idx](value);
  }
  ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That allows to always push the parsers and the formatters.

Let's say you have a parser that transforms the entered string into a number of milliseconds, and then another parse that transforms the milliseconds into a Date.

You'll need corresponding formatters: one that transforms a Date into a number of milliseconds, and a second one that transforms the milliseconds into a String. Having the formatters run in the inverse order of the parsers makes sense: you can simply do

```
ctrl.$parsers.push(stringToMillis);
ctrl.$formatters.push(millisToString);

...

ctrl.$parsers.push(millisToDate);
ctrl.$formatters.push(dateToMillis);
```